# Android How to set loop on AudioTrack?

Tags: android, loops, wav, pcm, audiotrack

I'm playing .wav files using AudioTrack.
I have a problem.
I set the setLoopPoints to loop my .wav files, but it doesn't work.

This is my sample code.

```
public class PleaseActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{
AudioTrack audioTrack;
public static final String MEDIA_PATH    = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/TEST";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
  Button play_button, stop_button;
  File file = null;
  byte[] byteData = null;
  Boolean playing = false;
  int bufSize;
  AudioTrack myAT = null;
  Thread play_thread = null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    play_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    stop_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);


    file = new File(MEDIA_PATH+"/untitled1.wav");
    byteData = new byte[(int) file.length()];   
    FileInputStream in = null;

    try {
      in = new FileInputStream(file);
      in.read(byteData);
      in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


    initialize();


    play_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {

        play_thread.start();
      }
    });

    //
    stop_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //
        if (myAT.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
          myAT.stop();
          play_thread = null;
          initialize();
        }
      }
    });

  }


  void initialize() {

    bufSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    myAT = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);



    play_thread = new Thread(this);
  }


  public void run() {
    if (myAT != null) {

      myAT.play();
      myAT.setLoopPoints(0, byteData.length, 2);
      myAT.write(byteData, 0, byteData.length);


    }
  }


}
```

I can play my wave files well, but setLoopPoints doesn't work!
Anybody helps me..

---

I solved this looping problems like this.
I have another problem.
whenever I wrote data into audiotrack,
I mean whenever audiotrack is repeated, some noise like "tick" is added at the first part.
I don't know how to eliminate this noise..
Is there anybody knows how to solve it?

```
class DLThread extends Thread
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            while(!DLThread.interrupted())
            {
                if (myAT != null) {
                      //

                      myAT.play();
                      myAT.flush();
                      myAT.write(byteData, 0, byteData.length);
                    }
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: You could subscribe to [`andraudio`](http://music.columbia.edu/mailman/listinfo/andraudio). You will likely get a useful response from them. Once you have added your email to the list, then you just send an email to andraudio@music.columbia.edu, and it will send it to everyone who is subscribed.

Answer (score 1):

public int setLoopPoints (int startInFrames, int endInFrames, int loopCount)

Sets the loop points and the loop count. The loop can be infinite. Similarly to setPlaybackHeadPosition, the track must be stopped or paused for the position to be changed, and ***must use the MODE_STATIC mode***.

Answer (score 1):

The tick is probably the wav file header. Try offsetting the playback by 44 bytes.